# Script that performs an action based on the contents of a UDP packet?

Tags: networking, scripting, udp

I'm trying to write a script that listens for broadcasted UDP packets on port 2088, read the data, and then POST to an URL.  Specifically, I'm trying to make a LIFX light turn red when I'm on the phone.  Whenever our phones change state (off-hook, on-hook, ringing, etc) it broadcasts its state on UDP 2088.

So, the pseudo-code would be something like:

```
Start Loop
Listen for UDP 2088 from source [my phone]
If data = [x] then send command to turn on lamp
else if data = [y] send command to turn off lamp
```

The biggest problem is I'm not sure how to actually grab the data from the packet.  It is readable in Wireshark, but when I run, for example, netcat, I get output that is unreadable.

> $ netcat -u -l 2088 -vv
> Bound on 0.0.0.0 2088
> Connection received on 192.168.250.51 2088
> ^C5

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to get `netcat` to exit after a UDP packet is with a busy loop and a timeout

```
while :
do
    data=$(nc -u -l -p 2088 -w 1 </dev/null 2>/dev/null)
    [ -n "$data" ] && printf "%s\n" "$(printf "%s" "$data" | hex)"
done
```

Tickle it with this type of code

```
echo hello | nc -q 1 -w 1 -u "$listeningHost" 2088
```

There are at least two different versions of `netcat` available. This example definitely works with *traditional*; I haven't tested with *openbsd*. Don't test on a single host - you really do need two connected hosts for this

Comment: Thanks.  Ended up getting waylaid by other projects.  I'll test soon hopefully.